# How to obtain in jQuery a list of elements ordered by position?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/KDk2N8VTXfPoJrEWAbc2?p=preview) I have these three (draggable) divs that can be positioned anywhere on the screen. What I need is to obtain, after the divs were dragged around, the order based on their left position (i.e. the left-most div should appear first in the list). How to achieve this in jQuery? In my attempt I always get the original order.

HTML

```
<p>Drag around the divs, then <button id="b1">click</button> to obtain the order (based on each left position)</p>


<div id="div1" 
style="width:60px;height:60px;background-color:orange;margin:20px;float:left">1</div>
<div id="div2" 
style="width:60px;height:60px;background-color:yellow;margin:20px;float:left">2</div>
<div id="div3" 
style="width:60px;height:60px;background-color:pink;margin:20px;float:left">3</div>
```

Javascript

```
$('#div1').draggable();
$('#div2').draggable();
$('#div3').draggable();

$('#b1').click(function() {
  var i = 1;
  var divs = $('div');
  divs.each(function () {
        var div = $(this);
        alert(div.text() + ' is number ' + i);
        i++;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `jQuery.prototype.offset` and `Array.prototype.sort` methods. The following snippet sorts the collection based on the left position of the elements:

```
$('#b1').click(function() {
    $('div').sort(function(a, b) {
        return $(a).offset().left > $(b).offset().left;
    }).each(function (i) {
        var div = $(this);
        alert(div.text() + ' is number ' + ++i);
    });
});
```